# Possible to activate a task in task scheduler based on memory usage?

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I am trying to set up a task that only runs at a certain level of RAM usage (and then won't run again for a period of time, preferably). Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a perfmon counter for memory which would create an event. Then use a task schedule trigger for that event. This [article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/netgeneral/Scripted-Networt-Defense-Part2.html) has an example used to react to DDoS attacks but might get you started.

Comment: @Matt Took my words out of my mouth. You should post it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing that you could do with what you have available is to create a Perfmon Counter for monitoring your memory. You can configure that count so that it  will create an Event in the Application Log. Scheduled tasks can be set to trigger to windows events. This [example](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/netgeneral/Scripted-Networt-Defense-Part2.html) will show you how to do this for a DDoS attack but should be easily translatable for your scenario.

Comment: Hello, this worked perfectly. I used the Available MBytes counter under the "Memory" category, in case anyone is wondering.